# Why do class based languages like c# and java still use files to store code?

Tags: object-oriented, language-design

In quite a few object oriented languages, especially the ones without free standing functions, it's now best practice to have one class per file, with the file name being the same as the class name. E.g. `MyClass.cs` storing class `MyClass` - this kind of makes the concept of a file pointless.

Is it known what the reasons were for modern languages like java and c# keeping files as opposed to other solutions such as e.g. a database per project?

Comment: Files are very flexible. For example, you can use whatever revision control system you want, you can edit source code with whatever editor, and so on.

Comment: @chi I chose this stack exchange due to this question being about a foundational concept of computer languages (in a broader sense), which admittedly isn't a perfect fit for any of the stackexchange sites I'm aware of. Also: http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1044/are-questions-about-programming-language-design-on-topic-here/1045#1045

Comment: In my own opinion, there is no deep "foundational" reason under this. It's a mere convention born out of practical simplicity, convenience, pragmatics and little else. I can see no science which influenced this decision. Even from a pure engineering point of view, this convention does not seem to be important. It merely helps the compiler to locate the source code without the programmer having to pass the whole of it to the compiler, or having to write interface/header files.

Comment: 1) This has nothing to do with computer *science*. 2) The reasons against databases are kind of obvious.

Comment: The *languages* don't specify that the source code be in files.  The languages just specify what the semantic meaning of various text is.  A particular compiler, which is one of any number of implementations of that language, may choose to accept the code to compile as files.  You could just as easily write your own C# or Java compiler that compiles code stored in a database (perhaps leveraging another, more mainstream, C# or java compiler under the hood, to compile the code after you extract it from the database).

Comment: 1) In Java you can have several classes in the same source file. 2) How does having a class per file make the concept of a file pointless. 3) Is it only modern languages that keep source code in files? Didn't a lot of old languages also use files to store source code?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you believe 1) that files are pointless and 2) why a database would somehow be better?

Comment: @Servy Obviously I disagree. :) The syntax, allowed set of characters, and presentation of the language as text are as much related to language design than the notion that a project links multiple source files into one program.

Comment: Isn't it the IDE that prefers text files over some sort of database?

Answer (score 5):

Source code files have many advantages over source code databases.  Just off the top of my head:

1) Easier to work with.  You can open a text file in an IDE of your choice, or any text editor.  A database would require an editor with a special interface.
2) Easier to share.  It's a lot easier to send someone a single file containing a small snipped of code if that small snippet of code is contained in a single file in the first place.
3) Easier to version-control.  Version control is designed for text, which means that text files can be versioned as-is by off-the-shelf version control software.  Trying to version database-based code would be a mess!

Keep in mind [the "minus 100 points" principle](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/): every language feature takes a lot of work to create and implement, so the question isn't "why doesn't a language have feature X," but rather "is feature X useful enough to make it worthwhile to overcome the barriers to implementing it?"  In the case of a feature like this, given that it would require a revamp of *our entire coding infrastructure* in order to support it, the barriers are higher than usual!

Comment: OP also insinuates that using files to store source code is something only "modern languages" do.

Comment: _"Is it known what the reasons were for modern languages like java and c# keeping files as opposed to other solutions such as e.g. a database per project?"_

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Older languages have freestanding functions, many of them don't even have classes, and the ones that do often spread them over multiple files. Thus the relation of File<->Class does not exist, and even where it exists it only accounts for part of the code base. Therefore the question doesn't make sense in the context of these languages. I asked the question in the context of languages where it makes sense.

Comment: @Peter Would you please explain how having one class per file makes the concept of file pointless?

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Files are a concept of organization and presentation. Same for classes. If the relation is 1:1, the only reason for opening MyClass.cs is to view and/or edit the class MyClass. If "opening file XYZ" always leads to "view and or edit class XYZ", the concept of a file  provides no value that isn't already provided by the concept of a class. If you ever try to explain to a 12-16 year old why and how we use files in these cases, you'll notice that they have a hard time understanding why the additional layer of "files" is needed.

Comment: Well, a Java source file can hold more than one class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968347/can-a-java-file-have-more-than-one-class . Also the concept of file is independant of the format of the content. Another question, does the conceptual problem you find with files applies only to classes of does it also apply to other information pieces that also have a 1:1 relationship with files like, for example jpg or png images?

Comment: `the only reason for opening MyClass.cs is to view and/or edit the class MyClass` -- Which is precisely the reason that each class goes into its own file, by convention.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Exactly, a file in these languages can hold any number of classes, yet this is rarely done, and there is little to no benefit where it is done. You bring up a good example with the jpg: A jpg and a .jpg file are the same thing. A class and a .cs file aren't. This is a leaky abstraction, which becomes visible in several instances, for example when renaming a class, when multiple classes are in the same file, or when having to re-organize both namespaces and disk location.

Comment: Probably stretching definitions a little bit here, but I wanted to add that every file system is a database and every file in it is a table/entry. The concept of a 1D table of characters is a concept that has proven itself over the last hundreds of years.

Comment: @null Very good point that catches the spirit of the question. In this mindset, the question should be "why was this form of database chosen over other, possibly more programmer friendly forms of databases". And the answer is most likely historical precedent, compatibility, cost, and risk.

Comment: @Peter: Because any system that gets in the way of version control, sharing, and arbitrary selection of editors **is not programmer-friendly.**  Those things are far more fundamental than whatever benefits a "code database" might bring.